# WordPress Search Custom Meta Field Only

Tags: custom-field, filters, search, meta-query

I have a recipe site where each recipe resides in a custom meta field called "recipes". I only want the contents of the meta field searched when users search the site.

The problem with my code below: When the number of search results exceeds the number of posts per page (10 - from main WP settings), it returns the results 3 times. In other words, if the search has 11 results the sequence repeats 3 times. 
No active plugins.

```
function my_search_filter( $query ) {
    global $searchtest;
    global $searchcount;
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => TRUE,
                'meta_key' => 'recipe',
                'meta_value' => sanitize_text_field($query->query_vars['search']), 
                'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
        $searchtest = new WP_Query ($args);
        if ($searchtest->have_posts()) { while ($searchtest->have_posts()) { $searchtest->the_post();  
            $searchtestresults[] = get_the_ID();
        }} wp_reset_postdata();
        $searchcount = count($searchtestresults);
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter' );
```

And in search.php

```
if ($searchtest->have_posts()) { while ($searchtest->have_posts()) {$searchtest->the_post();
...
post content
...
<div class="post-nav">
    <div id="post-nav-next"><?php next_posts_link('Older posts') ?></div>
    <div id="post-nav-prev"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer posts') ?></div>
</div><!-- /post-nav -->
```

This is still in development my local WAMP, so I have no link to provide. I have looked at related posts here and elsewhere on searching custom meta fields, and this code above is the closest I have come to getting the required results. I appreciate any help or alternate solutions.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Answer (score 0):

You are abusing `pre_get_posts` badly with that code. With `pre_get_posts` the point is to alter the main query. By doing that you reduce the number of necessary queries and save some processing time, plus keep the WordPress `globals`-- `$wp_query`, for example-- neat for any other code that might need them. What you are doing is creating new `global`s and populating them with new queries. You are just hiding those new queries inside `pre_get_posts`.

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, I believe you need this:

```
function search_meta_only_wpse_198762($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_main_query() && $qry->is_search()) {
    $qry->set(
      'meta_query', 
      array(
        array(
          'key' => 'recipe',
          'value' => sanitize_text_field($query->query_vars['search']),
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
      )
    );
    $qry->set('s',null);
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_meta_only_wpse_198762');
```