# How to get only post='product'

Tags: posts, search, woocommerce-offtopic, post-type

I am using [this code](http://adambalee.com/search-wordpress-by-custom-fields-without-a-plugin/) to search products from a wordpress/woocommerce website.
My requirment is URL will be like "http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product"
While `s=D34` is search string.

When user will search for a string. Data will be searched from All default fields+ product's `custom filed`. The below code work fine with http://localhost/wp/?s=D34 but when `&post_type=product` is concatenated with url then it say [image]

**Code is given below**

```
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
global $pagenow, $wpdb;


    if ( is_search() ) {
$where = preg_replace("/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
        $where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product') ";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );
```

**This is to prevent distinct values**

```
  function cf_search_distinct( $where ) {
        global $wpdb;
if ( is_search() ) {
    return "DISTINCT"; //to prevent duplicates
}

return $where;

}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'cf_search_distinct' );
```

So What modification is required?

`URL` http://localhost/wp/?orderby=price&post_type=product work fine

but what is wrong with http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product

Wordpress version is sixteen and 4.4. Woocommerce Plugin is installed

In both cases Query is

**Case 1:** http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product

**Case 2:** http://localhost/wp/?s=D34

```
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%D34%') OR (wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%D34%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%D34%'))) AND (wp_posts.post_password = '') AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'product') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'product')
```

Comment: You want to restrict the search to a single post type? Please explain in English what your goal here is.

Comment: This code work fine with  "http://localhost/wp/?s=D34" but i want to do it like  "http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product"

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, what you are doing is wildly complicated. All you should need is a simple `pre_get_posts` filter:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'modified_pre_get_posts' ); 
function modified_pre_get_posts( $query ) { 
  if ( $query->is_search() ) { 
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'product' ); 
  } 
  return $query; 
}
```

Plus your filter that adds `DISTINCT`.

`post_type` is a [query parameter rolled into Core](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars). Passing an URL such as `localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product` should by default limit your queries to the single named post type. You shouldn't have to do anything special to make that work. Your filter may in fact be causing trouble.

Comment: will it work with url like "http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product" I just updated question a bit

Comment: Well it dont works. it simply say "No products were found matching your selection"

Comment: It shows all porducts when url is,  http://localhost/wp/?post_type=product but do not work with "localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product

Comment: Then the problem is with the `s=D34` not the post type. That isn't matching. Where is that data stored?

Comment: One thing more is I also have to search from custom field that is the reason of that is to complicated

Comment: s=D34 is not post type. it is a search string. post_type is product.

Comment: Yes, I know what `s=D23` is! You need to add a `meta_query` to the search, very much like: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99861/21376 or http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/198858/21376 You also need to edit the question so that ***it is clear what you need***.

Comment: I made some changes to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;

    // a little debugging will help you..
    //print_r ($where);
    //die();

    if ( is_search() ) {

        $where = preg_replace("/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
        $where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product') ";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );
```

Comment: This code work fine with  "http://localhost/wp/?s=D34" but i want to do it like  "http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product"

Comment: it should work... if it doesn't then it's another problem.. which can't be seen on the current given question... try deactivating plugins... or try changing themes..

Answer (score 0):

You just add hidden input type by put these code below to your searchform.php

```
<input type="hidden" value="post" name="product" id="product" />
```

Comment: This make the url like http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&product=post

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type" id="product" />

This is correct form. but my porblem is not this. problem is when this type of url comes it is not treated as it should be.

Comment: Omg! I'm sorry for wrong solution for you.